# Is there a Haskell equivalent of Scala's Iterable.maxBy?

Tags: scala, haskell

Scala's [Iterable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterable) has `maxBy`:

> Finds the first element which yields the largest value measured by function `f`.

```
def maxBy[B](f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit cmp: Ordering[B]): A
```

Example:

```
scala> Seq(-2, 1).maxBy(Math.abs)
res0: Int = -2

scala> Seq(-2, 3).maxBy(Math.abs)
res1: Int = 3
```

What's the equivalent Haskell way to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Scala's `Iterable` is related to Haskell's `Traversable`. However, in this case, `Foldable` is enough to find the maximum of a given collection, so use [`maximumBy` from `Data.Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:maximumBy) in conjunction with `` compare `on` f `` (`on` from `Data.Function`) or `comparing f` (`comparing` from `Data.Ord`):

```
import Data.Foldable (maximumBy, Foldable)
import Data.Ord      (comparing)

maxBy :: (Foldable t, Ord a) => (b -> a) -> t b -> b
maxBy = maximumBy . comparing
```

Comment: I'd like to add that in Haskell, this `maxBy` would probably be called `maximumOn` to fit the naming convention. See [`sortBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy) and [`sortOn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn) in `Data.List`.

Answer (score 8):

Use
[`Data.List.maximumBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html)
and
[`Data.Ord.comparing`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Ord.html).

`comparing :: Ord a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering`

`maximumBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> a`

Example:

```
> import Data.Ord (comparing)
> import Data.List (maximumBy)

> maximumBy (comparing abs) [-2, 1]
-2

> maximumBy (comparing abs) [-2, 3]
3
```